# How to intercept video file in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-intercept

I'm trying to mock static video with cy.intercept

```
cy.intercept('/video.webm', { fixture: 'videos/video.webm' });
```

And that doesn't seems to work, it still return actual video instead of fixture one. I Also tried specify encoding `binary` and `null` like that

```
cy.intercept('/video.webm', { fixture: 'videos/video.webm,null' });
cy.intercept('/video.webm', { fixture: 'videos/video.webm,binary' });
```

But `null` gives me an error - The value "null" is invalid for option "encoding"

And with binary it seems that it returns an empty black video

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't fault it, this example works - plays the bunny vid which I have in `cypress/fixtures`.

Best guess is you have the wrong fixture path.

```js
cy.visit('https://www.webmfiles.org/demo-files/');

cy.intercept('/elephants-dream.webm', { fixture: 'big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm,null' })
cy.get('a[href="https://dl8.webmfiles.org/elephants-dream.webm"]')
  .click()
```

Comment: But I have a json intercept alongside
cy.intercept('/adminData.json', { fixture: 'adminData.json' });
which works just fine. Tried wildcard - still not works(

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I see examples with no wildcard in the docs. Will test and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, do not know why but this works for me.

```
cy.intercept('/video.webm', (req) => {
    req.continue((res) => {
        res.send({ fixture:'videos/video.webm' });
    });
});
```

PS: Also this answer from [@TesterDick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18366749/testerdick) actually works https://stackoverflow.com/a/73887996/12937539. But when I use video as source in the video tag and not in the link this not working. Maybe `video` tag with `source` the case

Comment: `req.continue()` sends the request to the server. Since you are unconditionally stubbing it's somewhat better to use `req.reply({ fixture:'videos/video.webm' })`.